# ¿Cómo navegar de un UIViewController en especifico a otro mediante NavigationController mediante código en Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode

voy comenzando en el lenguaje swift y mi duda es la siguiente:

Tengo tres UIViewController A,B y C.
De A => B no quiero muestre el UINavigationViewController
De B => C mostrar el UINavigationViewController para poder regresar a la ventana anterior.

Actualmente me muevo entre vistas utilizando:

```
let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerA") as! ViewControllerA

self.presentViewController(viewController,animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa "no quiero muestre el UINavigationViewController"? ¿Que en B no se muestre la "navigation bar"? ¿O que no se pueda regresar de B a A, es decir, que no tenga el botón de "back"?

Comment: que no aparezca en la parte superior de la pantalla en el top bar el UINavigationViewController y por ende que no pueda regresar de B a A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el ***view controller*** donde quieres que no se muestre la ***navigation bar***(*), puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
override public func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}

override public func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

---

(*) Creo que hay una confusión en la pregunta. Lo que creo que quisiste decir es que no quieres que se muestre la ***navigation bar*** como aclarabas en los comentarios. El ***navigation controller*** nunca se muestra, es solo un ***controller*** que se encarga de mostrar los demás ***view controllers***...